# GLSL ERROR: No vertex attrib is enabled in a draw call

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader, glsles

I am writing an app for android in OpenGL ES 2.0 and I have a problem with some shader code. Here it is:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
vec4 tempPosition;

void main() {
    tempPosition = vPosition;
    tempPosition.x = 2 - tempPosition.x;
    gl_Position = tempPosition.yxzw;
}
```

The line that causes the error is this one:

```
tempPosition.x = 2 - tempPosition.x;
```

I am enabling and disabling vertex atrrib arrays each time I want to draw something. Before i draw i call this: `GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(sPosition);` and after i drew i call this 
`GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(sPosition);`

What am I doing wrong? How to substract x from 2?

**EDIT:**

If I change the line that causes the error to this:

```
tempPosition.xz = vec2(2,0) - tempPosition.xz;
```

than it works, but why cant i substract with a single number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the GLSL version used with ES 2.0 (which somewhat mysteriously is version 1.00), there are no implicit type conversions. You can't add a value of type `int` to a value of type `float`, or a vector of floats.

This is specified in the introduction of chapter 4 "Variables and Types" of the spec:

> The OpenGL ES Shading Language is type safe. There are no implicit conversions between types.

and in more detail for this case in section 5.9 "Expressions", where the `+` operator is defined:

> The two operands must be the same type, or one can be a scalar float and the other a float vector or matrix, or one can be a scalar integer and the other an integer vector.

Therefore, you need to use float constants when operating with floats:

```
tempPosition.x = 2.0 - tempPosition.x;
```

The more interesting case is why your second attempt worked, since you're also mixing different types:

```
tempPosition.xz = vec2(2,0) - tempPosition.xz;
```

This is legal because constructors **can** be used to convert types, and are the primary mechanism to do so. For example, you could have written your original expression as:

```
tempPosition.x = float(2) - tempPosition.x;
```

This looks awkward for a constant value, but would make much more sense if the integer value were in a variable:

```
int foo = ...;
tempPosition.x = float(foo) - tempPosition.x;
```

Back to the vector case, section 5.4.2 "Vector and Matrix Constructors" specifies:

> If the basic type (bool, int, or float) of a parameter to a constructor does not match the basic type of the object being constructed, the scalar construction rules (above) are used to convert the parameters.

This means that you can use an `int` value as the argument to a constructor of a `vec2`, even though it contains `float` values. In this case, the value is automatically converted. In other words, your second statement is equivalent to:

```
tempPosition.xz = vec2(float(2), float(0)) - tempPosition.xz;
```

IMHO, it's still much cleaner to not rely on implicit conversions, and write:

```
tempPosition.xz = vec2(2.0, 0.0) - tempPosition.xz;
```

Note that full OpenGL is different from OpenGL ES in this respect. In full GLSL, there are implicit type conversions. Which I personally find unfortunate, because I believe that type safety is a useful principle.

Comment: Good answer. FWIW, the mysterious reason of GLSL version being 1.0 on OpenGL 2.0 is that on that version was GLSL introduced first; before that (OpenGL 1.0) it was a fixed pipeline instead (no shaders involved). On OpenGL 2.0 they turned it into a programmable pipeline for more control and possibilities.